# How to use imports in TypeScript without Node.JS nor external libraries?

Tags: typescript

I want to use the `export` keyword and the `import` keyword in order to link my TypeScript files.

TypeScript does not support the configuration `"module": "ES6"` with the `--outFile` parameter.

My project processes those files one by one so I need this option. Once the TypeScript file is compiled, I pass it to the Closure Compiler jar.

I do not want to use Node.JS or any other libraries. I just want to use native JavaScript but with types.

How can I do ?
Does the `/// <reference path="myFile.ts" />` syntax allow me to have a similar approach ? I guess if I use that "annotation", I must use another way to export things ?
If it is possible, I want a future proof solution and I really think that import/export is the future :/ and then no need to rewrite my code later to use import/export...

Comment: I have the same requirements as my company is very restricted on installing libraries on servers. Did you find any solution?

Comment: Unfortunately, no.